# Why is this javascript function running without being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(SetupButtonClicks());

function SetupButtonClicks() {
    $('#btnJavaPHP').click(DoPHPStuff());
}

function DoPHPStuff() {
    //stuff
}
```

I have this code in my javascript file, when I debug it I see it call `SetupButtonClicks()` like it should but after that is done it calls `DoPHPStuff()`. `DoPHPStuff()` should only be called when `btnJavaPHP` is clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change your SetupButtonClicks function:

```
$('#btnJavaPHP').click(DoHPStuff);
```

The way you've got it coded, you're telling Javascript to *call* the function, not to *use* it as the "click" handler. The parentheses are an *operator* that causes a function to be called.

Comment: @jamone you're $(document).ready is probably still wrong... make sure to change that too.

Comment: @galambalazs yeah, I fixed the $(document).ready line at the same time. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `()`.

By writing `$(document).ready(SetupButtonClicks())`, you are *calling* `SetupButtonClicks` and passing its return value to `ready`.
Similarly, by writing `$('#btnJavaPHP').click(DoPHPStuff())`, you are *calling* `DoPHPStuff` (immediately) and passing whatever it returns to `click()`.

You need to pass the functions themselves by writing `$(document).ready(SetupButtonClicks)` and `$('#btnJavaPHP').click(DoPHPStuff)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function DoPHPStuff() {
    //stuff
}

function SetupButtonClicks() {
    $('#btnJavaPHP').click(DoPHPStuff);
}

$(document).ready(SetupButtonClicks);
```

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of a function declaration, a pair of parentheses following a function's identifier causes the function to execute. Examples:

```
// function declaration; function not executed
function SetupButtonClicks() {

}

// function executed
SetupButtonClicks();

// function not executed
SetupButtonClicks;
```